# How Do I Add Google Analytics in my Blogger Blog?

Tags: google-analytics, blogger

The blog was created in 2010 or 2011 so I do not remember if it was Classic Template that was used. I tried adding my tracking id in the blog settings. I also tried copying the tracking code in the HTML of my template. That did not work I guess because according to the instructions the tracking code should appear right before the `</head>` tag. I see the tracking code in my source page but there is a lot of script and css code before the `</head>` tag.

Normally when I add the tracking code in my Ruby on Rails applications the tracking code is immediately found (or at least it was the last time I implemented tracking). However now my account says "tracking not installed". I wonder since it has been a while if I have to wait for the tracking to be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Your tracking should be immediate. To check if data is being sent to Analytics you can open developer tools in Chrome and go to the networking tab. You should see something like this:

[image]

If you see utm.gif being called then Analytics is receiving data. Unless your unique ID code is wrong.

In Blogger though you shouldn't have to do much, there is a setting in the administration panel just for this (image taken from [WikiHow - Google Analytics in Blogger](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Google-Analytics-to-Blogger):

[image]

Comment: It took a while but the status in Google Analytics now says Receiving Data instead of Tracking Not Installed. There must be something unique to Blogger that takes so long for it to update in Google Analytics. With all my Ruby on Rails applications it took maybe 1 minute for the status to change to Receiving Data. Oh well at least it's active now.